# Append large number of files together without starting/ending lines

Tags: batch-file, append

I am looking to append multiple files to a main file excluding the starting 10 lines and ending line. After appending, I will be deleting these files. Currently my best attempt:

```
@echo off
SET allFiles=S:\scratch\test1.txt S:\scratch\test2.txt S:\scratch\test3.txt 
SET mainFile=S:\scratch\main.txt
SET tempFile=S:\scratch\tmp.txt
break>S:\scratch\tmp.txt
(for %%a in (%allFiles%) do (
   more +10 %%a > %tempFile%
   copy /Y %mainFile% %%a
   type %%a %tempFile% > %mainFile%
   del %%a
))
del %tempFile%
%txtEditr% %mainFile%
```

This skips the first 10 lines when appending but does not skip the last line. It is also slow for large files and/or many files.

Is there a better/faster way to append a number of files this way or should I look into writing out line by line in a program?

Answer (score 0):

This batch solution might be to slow for large files,
It skips 10 lines and then reads line per line storing the current line and
printing the previous line - so being able to skip the very last.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET allFiles=S:\scratch\test1.txt S:\scratch\test2.txt S:\scratch\test3.txt 
SET mainFile=S:\scratch\main.txt
( for %%F in (%allFiles%) do (
    Set "Last="
    for /f "skip=10 delims=" %%L in (
      ' Findstr "^" %%F '
    ) Do (
      If defined Last Echo:!Last:~1!
      Set "Last=#%%L"
    )
  )
) >"%mainFile%"
%txtEditr% %mainFile%
```

This not asked for PowerShell script should be faster.

```
$allFiles = @('S:\scratch\test1.txt','S:\scratch\test2.txt','S:\scratch\test3.txt')
$mainFile = 'S:\scratch\main.txt'
Del $mainFile
ForEach ($File in $allFiles){
  Get-Content $File | Select -Skip 10 | Select -SkipLast 1 | Out-File $mainFile -Append -Enc Ascii
}
```